# how to add Checkmark TableView Multiple Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I want to make the user multiple choice (years) or choose (all) and the rest of the cells disappear (checkmark).
I want the user can not cancel each (checkmark).

This My Code :-

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
cell?.accessoryType = .checkmark
 }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! yearsCell 
cell.years?.text = Years[indexPath.row]
return cell }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to include more information. What are you hoping for and what isn't working for you?

Comment: @Magnas I want to get the following: -
1. The user can choose any (years) or Cancel.
2. When the user's choice (all) the rest disappear (checkmark) of all cells.
3. The user can not cancel all (checkmark) Default (All).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I do this is by storing the `selectedindexPath`'s in an array, then reload the `tableView` to change the cells that were selected, this way you avoid problems with cell re-use, this might look like this (un-tested).

```
var selectedIndexPathArray = Array<NSIndexPath>()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    selectedIndexPathArray.append(indexPath)
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! yearsCell 
    cell.years?.text = Years[indexPath.row]
    cell.accessoryType = .none
    for sip in selectedIndexPathArray {
        if indexPath == sip {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        }
    }
    return cell 
}
```

Comment: Good but I can't Multiple choice for years

Comment: @MajedDkahellalah Okay, I have modified it to be an array so you should be able to select multiple years.

Comment: You may also want to write some logic to prevent duplicates in the `selectedIndexPathArray` (if the user taps the cell again) .. and also consider allowing users to remove selected years.

Comment: thanks replay .. select multiple worked , but :- 1- i can't remove checkmark . 2- i need if user select word ( All ) remove all chackmarks from rest cells. 3- i need Default selected word ( All ) if start view .   thanks

Comment: You are going to need to figure some of this out for yourself man. Use the example and try some stuff out, put an `indexPath` in the array to set your default, add some logic on the array `didSet` to handle your other states.

Answer (score 1):

Like So:

**SWIFT 3**

```
// To checkmark the cell
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at:indexPath.row)
cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
```

---

```
// To make it unselectable
```

Use the `tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method and check if the `indexPath.row` is the row for the cell you just selected, and `return false`.

Answer (score 0):

The cell is reusable. For example, the cell used to display 1st row might be used to display 10th row when scroll down. Therefore, you need a array store the checkmark status for each row, some code like:

- didSelect: array[indexpath.row] = !array[indexpath.row]
- cellForRow: setCheckmark(array[indexpath.row])

MORE: google how and why a cell is reused in tableview